# changing values of a dictionary to a list

Tags: python

I have the following code snippet where am assigning values to dictionary..currently the dictionary values are getting printed as normal values..i want to them to convert to a list,how do i change the "database[data]=value" line to achieve this?

```
database={}
.......
database[data]=value //assigning value to a dictionary
print database
...............

Expected output:-
internal_dep = {'313115': ['313113'],'213114': ['213103'] }

Current output:-
internal_dep = {'313115': '313113','213114': '213103' }
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. The answerers have interpreted it in at least 2 different ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try:

```
database[data]=[value]
```

If you only want to print it this way, you can try:

```
print({k:[v] for k, v in database.items()})
```

Answer (score 0):

A list cannot (easily) be used as a dictionary in Python—although Lisp does represent dictionaries this way. However, you can get at either the values or the keys and convert them to a list like so:

```
print list(database.values())
```

or

```
print list(database.keys())
```